A movie about woman sleeping with a married man
I can't remember the name of this movie I saw.
It's about a woman who's sleeping with a married man and finds out she's pregnant. 
The man wants her to get an abortion but she refuses. So he acts supportive and says he'll go to the OBGYN with her. Once they're there he secretly pays off the doctor to perform an abortion on her. 
As revenge she goes to his daughters school, takes her out into a field and kills her.
Country: Pretty sure it was a foreign film but can't remember what country
Year: I know it was on Netflix last year and released in 2000s.
Genre: Drama

Every country is foreign for someone.

O Lobo atrás da Porta (2013)

A mother and housewife named Sylvia goes to pick up her daughter
  Claudinha at school, and finds her missing. She is told by the teacher
  that she received a phone call from someone who claimed to be her,
  saying that she was sick and that a neighbor would come pick her up
  instead.
At the police station, Sylvia, Bernardo, and the teacher are
  questioned for possible clues about who could have taken the girl.
  Bernardo reveals that he strongly suspects it was the work of a woman
  named Rosa, with whom he'd been carrying an affair for some time. Rosa
  is taken in for questioning. At first, she is reluctant to speak, and
  tells the police that she was blackmailed into taking the girl at the
  behest of a woman named Bete, whose husband was supposedly involved in
  an affair with Sylvia. This is exposed as a lie by the police after an
  investigation of the neighborhood reveals that no such woman exists,
  and after the police officer threatens her, Rosa confesses everything.
Rosa and Bernardo met a train station after the latter saw on her the
  train and followed her. Their affair begins passionately, but Rosa
  becomes upset when she discovers that Bernardo lied to her about being
  married and having a family. She tells him that she does not mind
  being his lover for the meantime, but begins to visit his wife and
  child, befriending her by pretending to be a mutual acquaintance of an
  old friend and presenting his daughter with gifts. Upon being told
  about this by his wife, Bernardo becomes enraged and fights with Rosa,
  abusing her and telling her never to seek out his family again. Rosa
  ignores this request, and tries to get back at him by paying a woman
  at a bar to phone him, pretending to be the wife of Sylvia's lover to
  try and sabotage their relationship. She also discovers that Bernardo
  has been rekindling his relationship with Sylvia anyways, and that it
  is likely that their affair is at its end.
During an argument about the future of their relationship, Rosa
  reveals that her period is late. Rosa complies with Bernardo's request
  to have a pregnancy test, which turns out positive. She tells Bernardo
  that he can resume his life without regard for what becomes of her,
  but that she is having the child no matter what. Some time later,
  Bernardo tricks Rosa into visiting a practitioner acquaintance of his,
  who drugs Rosa and performs an abortion against her will.
Devastated and unstable, Rosa tries to arrange one last meeting with
  Bernardo, but is rebuffed. She picks up Claudinha at school, and
  eventually takes her to an abandoned lot, where she pulls out a pistol
  from her purse, kills the child, and burns her corpse with gasoline.
  The film ends with a voiceover from the police officer describing
  Rosa's statement about the matter: she feels no remorse, and
  understands the full weight of her actions. She has no desire for an
  attorney, does not care about what will happen to her, and does not
  wish for anyone's forgiveness.

